# How do I redirect the STDOUT for a PHP process that is invoked via screen -d -m?

Tags: php, linux, logging, stdout, gnu-screen

I'm invoking a PHP process using `screen -d -m` so that it launches the process in a new `screen` session.  I'd like to store the STDOUT of that PHP process in a log file.  Normally, I can simply add `> output.log` and that log file will be created and populated with the STDOUT of the PHP process.  This does not work when the PHP process is launched within a new screen session.  The log file is created but it is never written to.

**How do I record the STDOUT of this PHP process?**

```
screen -d -m php process.php user_input_1 user_input_1 > output.log
```

I believe this command is redirecting the STDOUT of the `screen` command to `output.log` and not the STDOUT of the `process.php`.

Comment: Why are you using screen?  Might be better off just backgrounding the process.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to screen is to use tmux.  Here is a good overview of what it offers over screen: http://dominik.honnef.co/posts/2010/10/why_you_should_try_tmux_instead_of_screen/

It's a scriptable piece of software, so it seems likely that you can control the output.  This post (http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/capture-tmux-output-the-much-less-painful-way/) seems to indicate as much.  The commands listed on there should be scriptable.

YMMV, I haven't tried this.  I think I'd probably try a different method (maybe using a logging server).  Let me know if you have any other questions on this, or if you're pursuing a different approach.

Now gimmie my karma ;)